# Check the element is the number in the array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of elements consisting of digits and names of images.
I want to check that the i element of the array is the number or name of the image. 
Can someone suggest me the solution?
Thanks.

This is my array:

```
var images = ["icon_theme_sports_badminton",9,1,"icon_theme_sports_baseball",7,"icon_theme_sports_basketball",3,"icon_theme_sports_bicycle",6,"icon_theme_sports_bowling",2,"icon_theme_sports_football",4,"icon_theme_sports_golf","icon_theme_sports_pingpong",8,5,"icon_theme_sports_s_ski","icon_theme_sports_s_swimming",0]
```

This is my processing code before adding numbers to the array

```
 func collectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier ("collection_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectCollectionViewCell
        cell.image_icon.image = UIImage (named: images [indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `var images = [` will not even compile because Swift is strictly typed language and when u declare var without specific data type specified it infers the data type based on the elements passed to it, so as soon as you pass string and number mixed value it gives you error stating heterogeneous collection can only be inferred with `[Any]` and clearly you dont even have [Any] declared in your statement so it wont even compile

Comment: Why do you have numbers or images name? What represent the numbers. It's a simple task to check if it's an Int or not, but your issue might lies in the construction of that array. So why do you have numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to initialise your array as,

```
var images = ["icon_theme_sports_badminton",9,1,"icon_theme_sports_baseball",7,"icon_theme_sports_basketball",3,"icon_theme_sports_bicycle",6,"icon_theme_sports_bowling",2,"icon_theme_sports_football",4,"icon_theme_sports_golf","icon_theme_sports_pingpong",8,5,"icon_theme_sports_s_ski","icon_theme_sports_s_swimming",0] as [Any]
```

Now you can update 'cellForItemAt' method like following,

```
func collectionView (collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier ("collection_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SelectCollectionViewCell
if images[indexPath.row] is Int {
    cell.image_icon.image = UIImage (named: "Default.png")
 } else {
    cell.image_icon.image = UIImage (named: images [indexPath.row])
 }   
return cell
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This code block may help you

```
var images: [Any] = ["icon_theme_sports_badminton",9,1,"icon_theme_sports_baseball",7,"icon_theme_sports_basketball",3,"icon_theme_sports_bicycle",6,"icon_theme_sports_bowling",2,"icon_theme_sports_football",4,"icon_theme_sports_golf","icon_theme_sports_pingpong",8,5,"icon_theme_sports_s_ski","icon_theme_sports_s_swimming",0]


for arrayElement in images {

    if let numberElement = arrayElement as? Int {
        print("Array element is number: \(numberElement)")
    } else if let stringElement = arrayElement as? String {
        print("Array element is string: \(stringElement)")
    } else {
        print("Array element is not a number or string: \(arrayElement)")
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]